The new and "improved" tag page doesn't show the [ask question] button unless the tag is being watched
The Ask Question button is missing on tag pages when one is not watching that specific tag.
For example, when I'm watching c# I can ask questions:

But not when I'm not watching that tag:

In case it matters I'm seeing it with Firefox 129.0.2 on linux.
On other sites, where the new tag page hasn't rolled out yet, like meta, the button is visible, no matter if I'm currently following it or not.
Does that mean I must watch a tag to ask questions in it? /s

I have switched this one to status-bydesign as it's not a bug.
While we demonstrated this in mockups here under experiment 3, I will admit that it wasn't communicated as clearly as it could have been.
When we reviewed this page, we found that approximately less than 4% of all questions over the last year came from the tagged questions page. Our intention with this redesign was to make the important contents of the page, the questions, easier to focus on by reducing the total number of possible actions on the page. With such a low number, we felt comfortable removing the button.

If that's the reasoning then why show the button when one is watching the tag?

Oof, as far as I can tell unwatched tags are the only page without a [Ask Question] button. This really breaks expectations. Especially since the watched tag page still has it.

Please see my answer as I think you're not monitoring any of the other posts about the tag wiki changes anymore.

First, 4% is 1 in 25. That's not much, but it's not insignificant either. Second, what harm was the button doing? Clutter? Because I think being consistent across SO is much more important than removing one button from the tag page.

@bad_coder feel free to ping me in chat somewhere as I am not sure I follow what you  are referring to because the leaderboard is still on the tag wiki page on the side bar.

@Anerdw From a design perspective, it comes from the need to reduce cognitive load on the actions we want users to take on that page. Which, in this case, is interacting with the question list or going to the tag wiki page. I don't think it was causing harm, but I don't think it's unreasonable to argue that if someone wanted to ask a question, they know where to find the button to do it.

@Anerdw The 4% number is just for how often the button was pushed from that location, not if the questions ended up being asked. I think that distinction matters, but it might be splitting hairs to ask a data scientist to look into it to understand. Ultimately, the ask-a-question flow starts 96% of the time elsewhere. I respect the dislike for it being removed; nobody likes having their cheese moved.

@cafce25 There are a couple of others /tags, /users, /saves, though it would be weird to have one there. There might be others that I am not thinking of.
